# Change gcc compiler version o n Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compilation, ubuntu-18.04

i'm trying to change mi gcc compiler version. I installed gcc 9, but when i tru to see my gcc version with the command

```
'''gcc --version'''
```

i allways get this:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 Copyright (C) 2017 Free
Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for
copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can i change my gcc compiler version?